# Sum of a series using for loop in C

Tags: c

I am a complete beginner in C and learning to code on my own using the internet and i have written the following code to find the sum of the series 
s= 1/1 + 2^2/2 + 3^3/3 .........
using the for loop in c.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
     int i,n;
     float a,b;
     printf("Enter the number of terms in the series: \n");
     scanf("%i",&n);
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
          a=pow(i,i)/i;
          b=a+a;
     }
     printf("The sum of the series is %f\n",b);
     return 0;
}
```

I am pretty sure that i am making a logical error but i seem to be too dumb or slow to figure that out so i would appreciate for someone to point that out for me. Thank you :)

Comment: What is the output you are receiving?  What is the output you expected?

Comment: you want to initialize `b` (BTW, `sum` would be a better identifier) to zero and keep adding to it `b = b + a;`

Comment: You will get better results if you use doubles instead of floats.  A float is not guaranteed to be able to hold more than about 7 significant digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm, you missed one part, which is adding the output of the current calculation to the total sum.

This statement:

```
b=a+a
```

Will give 'b' the value of a + a, so when passing 4 as a input argument the b will have the following values:

```
b = 1 + 1
b = 2 + 2
b = 9 + 9
b = 64 + 64
```

This can be fixed by adding the value to the total sum:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
     int n;
     float sum = 0;
     printf("Enter the number of terms in the series: \n");
     scanf("%i",&n);
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
          float a = pow(i,i)/i;
          sum += a;
     }
     printf("The sum of the series is %f\n", sum);
     return 0;
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Enter the number of terms in the series:                                                                                                                                     
4                                                                                                                                                                            
The sum of the series is 76.000000
```

Comment: Thanks!! I understand where i was making the mistake....thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

If B is trying to be your sum, you're going to want. b = b + a. not b = a + a.

Otherwise you're not summing your results together, you're calculating 2a.

Don't forget to initialize your variables as well.

Comment: This will require initializing `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing a declaration b=0, b=b+a...

Comment: `a` is assigned a value, `b` is not.

Comment: You've got part of an answer here. That's a good explanation, but showing the adjusted code would help a lot more.